# Como Modificar y/o eliminar u Ocultar campos en el modulo de ventas de odoo13?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo13

El caso es que necesito "Gestionar un almacen", no obstante en la empresa no basta con instalar el modulo de inventario, ya que necesitan " generarse solicitudes al inventario"

es una accion adicional, a mi se me ha ocurrido instalar el modulo de ventas ya que tiene "Pedidos" pero NO puedo dejar que se observen el coste, el Precio, el total, el iva y la cantidad disponible de productos en el formulario de solicitud

Soy algo nuevo utilizando y/o manipulando Odoo 13
Por favor si es necesario, expliquenme graficamente o paso a paso... les agradezco un monton!
[image: Aqui se observa el formulario de la vista, pero no sé como quitar estos campos que les menciono]

Answer (score 0):

Directorio --> Odoo / addons / views / xml

Comentar para el diseño de las páginas (Creo que es lo que necesitas: esconder el coste,  iva, etc.):

`<!--<field name="estimated_cost" widget="monetary" /> -->`

Cambiar de nombres de campos:

`<field name="name">Realizar un Pedido</field><!--Canviar nombres-->`

Para quitar opciones de los menús desplegables:

`<!--<menuitem action="product.product_supplierinfo_type_action" id="menu_product_pricelist_action2_purchase" parent="menu_purchase_config" sequence="1"/>-->`

Hay mucha cantidad de etiquetas en los xml, si estás en la interfaz de odoo en modo desarrollador y pasas el ratón por encima puedes ver los nombres de las etiquetas. Así las encontrarás más fácilmente.